# Can I use a vpn for a game, while using no vpn for the software I use to stream the game

Tags: networking, vpn, connection, streaming, gaming

Just wondering if its possible to use a vpn connection for 1 sole program ( a game) while the software I use for streaming the game live to twitch (OBS) uses my normal connection to my ISP. Reason is because I would like to connect to the euro servers while playing and streaming my game with reasonable quality

My down is 100 Mbps and upload is 10 Mbps from canada.

Comment: It might be helpful if you updated this question with some more information like what type of VPN you're using (e.g. openvpn?) and what OS you're running (Windows?). I believe some VPN clients actually have built in options to do this or something similar (e.g. routing traffic targeted toward certain IP ranges over the VPN interface), though it might by more typical of corporate VPNs.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 provides a new function to achieve your goal. It's called "App-triggered VPN" and "Traffic filters".

> App-triggered VPN
>
> VPN profiles in Windows 10 can be configured to connect automatically
>   on the launch of a specified set of applications. This feature was
>   included in Windows 8.1 as "On demand VPN". The applications can be
>   defined using the following: •Package family name for Universal
>   Windows Platform (UWP) apps •File path for Classic Windows
>   applications

For detailed information, please read this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/vpn-profile-options?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).